# Cascade.DeleteBehaviour and connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have following code

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}

public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Comment> modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ToTable(nameof(Comment));
    modelBuilder.HasKey(comment => comment.id);

    modelBuilder.HasOne(comment => comment.Post)
                .HasMany(post => post.Comments)
                .HasForeignKey(comment => comment.PostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehaviour.Cascade);

}
```

So when i remove post, does comments connected to the post will be also removed?

Comment: Welcome! I am confused by your question. Is it really about removing comments when a post is removed? Or do you need to give us a question about your code sample? Thanks

Comment: Improved code formatting

Comment: Cascaded deletes is a dbase engine feature.  Works very well when you normalize the data, doesn't when you are forced to de-normalize for perf reasons.  Nothing in your object model says that it won't work, you made the denormalized data, the Id member, the primary key.  As you should.  Only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.